# Separating options with logical OR ("|") in C++

Tags: c++, bitflags

I know that options can be added when initializing an instance of fstream, for example:

```
fstream file("filename.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

In this case there are 3 options.
I have several questions:

1. How should I implement that in my own function?
2. Should I define any const values or marcos?
3. How to parse the options and deal with the them properly?

Comment: **Bitmask** is the word you are searching for.

Comment: `|` **is not** the logical OR. It is the ["bitwise OR"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) and it is a completely different thing. But the [bitwise operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) are what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I implement that in my own function?

Make it a [bitmask type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType):

> The bitmask type supports a finite number of bitmask elements, which are distinct non-zero values of the bitmask type, such that, for any pair `Ci` and `Cj`, `Ci & Ci != 0` and `Ci & Cj == 0`. In addition, the value `0` is used to represent an empty bitmask, with no values set.

> Should I define any const values or macros?

The values are typically constants representing consecutive powers of two, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

> How to parse the options and deal with the them properly?

You never need to "parse" these options - all you need to do is to check if a given option is present or not. You can do it with `&` operator:

```
openmode x = ios::in | ios::out;
if (x & ios::in) {
    ... // TRUE
}
if (x && ios::binary) {
    ... // False
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These are bitmasks.

> How should I implement that in my own function?
>
> Should I define any const values or marcos?

No need for macros. I prefer enums:

```
namespace options {
    enum options_enum : unsigned {
        in       = (1u << 0),
        out      = (1u << 1),
        binary   = (1u << 2),
        whatever = (1u << 3),
    };
};
```

> How to parse the options and deal with the them properly?

By masking:

```
bool in = option_argument & options::in;
```